# How to remove terms with negligible constant from expression?

Tags: functions, function-construction

I'm working on a Notebook that requires the integration of multiple expressions (sometimes numeric, sometimes analytic). These expressions are normally of the form:

```
E^(-0.780412 xm^2 - 0.324027 ym^2) (2.61869*10^-17 E^(0.324027 xm^2) - 0.0555444 E^(0.456384 xm^2) xm + E^(0.456384 xm^2)xm Erf[0.36381 xm] (1.74579*10^-17 - 1.47748*10^-33 Erf[0.36381 ym]) + (-2.21623*10^-33 E^(0.324027 xm^2) + 4.70079*10^-18 E^(0.456384 xm^2) xm) Erf[0.36381 ym])
```

(Above was the result of an analytic integration). How would I be able to write a function that removes any expressions with a co-efficient less than 10^(-10)? (or sets them to 0).

These will sometimes have variables (such as `xm` and `ym`) and mostly be `Erf` functions. For example, for the case above, I would want it reduced to only include the term:

```
- 0.0555444 xm E^(0.456384 xm^2) E^(-0.780412 xm^2 - 0.324027 ym^2)
```

If needed I can provide the exact code that resulted in this result, or more examples of the output. Thanks!

Comment: Look at the function "Chop"

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much

Comment: @DanielHuber follow up question - is there a way to have an analytic integral ignore any terms lower than a certain magnitude (I want to reduce computation time). Thanks again!

Comment: `Chop` has a second argument that can help but a minimal example would help someone write a concrete answer.

Comment: For a purely symbolic term this is not possible because nothing is known about is size. But for numerical factors you may e.g. write:  `a + 10^(-10 ) b a /. x_?NumericQ /; Abs[x] < 10^-6 -> 0` what evaulates to `a `

Answer (score 0):

expr is your expression. Try this:

```
Plus @@ Map[If[Abs[Part[#, 1]] < 10^-10, 0, #] &, 
  List @@ (expr // Expand)]

(* -0.0555444 E^(-0.324028 xm^2 - 0.324027 ym^2) xm  *)
```

or like this:

```
(expr // Expand) /. x_Times /; Abs[x[[1]]] < 10^-10 -> 0
```

with the same effect.

Have fun!